# RhoMobile - locally storage and Rhom API

Tags: rhomobile

I am fairly new to using Rhomobile, however I am not fully understanding how the local storing works and how to use the Rhom API.

I've set up the RhoStudio and run the configurations.
What I am trying to achieve is basically have two data models (with property bags as default): one for wards, and one for patients so I can create patient and ward objects.

Eventually I would like to list the wards, and the patients that are assigned to the ward objects.

Can someone explain how I use the Rhom API to be able to achieve this?

I have ran a simulation so once I have something like: /app/Patient/{131199009368684.14}/show in the web inspector, so I am assuming that I will need to create an association of some sort.. And then filter it out with a group Query.

In my personal opinion using the RhoMobile Doc's are not helpful enough.

Many thanks if someone can give me a typical example.

Answer (score 0):

Rhodes auto generates unique ids for each instance of a Module, when it is created. This property is called "object". "131199009368684.14" what you got is the "object" of a particular patient that you created. What you can do to link the patients to the ward is:-

Add an additional property to the Patient Model that stores the "object" of the Ward instance you want to link that particular patient to. Thus you will be able to list all the patients in a particular ward by running a find query on column that stores the object of the Ward in the Patient table, by supplying it the particular Ward's object.

Hope this is useful.